# Nested attributes won't bind to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to allow nested attributes to be submitted with my model during a post. I'm using RubyMine as my IDE, and when debugging, I'm able to see the correct values that are being posted, but I can't figure out what they aren't then being set in the `@model`.

**Models**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_prices, allow_destroy: true
end
class ProductPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

**View Code**

```
<%= form_for :model, url: products_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <table>
        <%= f.fields_for :product_prices do |ff| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= ff.text_field :start_date %></td>
                <td><%= ff.text_field :end_date %></td>
                <td><%= ff.text_field :price %></td>
                <td><%= ff.check_box :_destroy %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>

    <%= link_to 'Go Back', products_url %>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller (Updated!)**

```
def create
    @model = Product.new(product_params)

    if @model.save
      redirect_to @model
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

private
def product_params
    params.require(:model).permit(:id, :name, :description, :is_active, product_prices_attributes: [:id, :product_id, :start_date, :end_date, :price, :_destroy])
end
```

**Edit**
Below is my params structure:

```
{
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"Hu+mTRWtTLz3wvPOPPw/OdkP1DWqneT2bR+mc2LlWe0eFX9LOYjB28005gjIcRDn3JskV4d7V+2IojIalyQc2A==",
    "model"=>{
      "name"=>"SENATE BILL OLTEST",
      "description"=>"sdfasd",
      "is_active"=>"1",
      "product_prices"=>{
        "start_date"=>"1/1/2013",
        "end_date"=>"",
        "price"=>"15.00",
        "_destroy"=>"0"
      }
    },
    "commit"=>"Create"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `autosave: true` in your `belongs_to :product`?

Comment: @augustoccesar I just tried that, and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: i see... but the values are being binded (on the code debug, not the database) correctly to the ProductPrice array inside Product?

Comment: @augustoccesar I'm able to see the correct values in params, but the values don't appear to be binding correctly to my model instance variable, therefore not making it to the db.

Comment: oh, so you should keep the `autosave: true` because when you solve the issue that is not allowing the values to be binded, it will be necessary. As about the not binding issue, are you sure that the `params` structure are the one you described in the `.permit()`?

Comment: @augustoccesar I'm positive. I updated the question with structure of data

Comment: What happens if you change in the `params` the value `product_prices_attributes ` to `product_prices `?

Comment: @augustoccesar that results in an exception: ProductPrice(#87869240) expected, got Array(#19493560)

Comment: try `product_prices: [{:id, :product_id, :start_date, :end_date, :price, :_destroy}]` on the params permit

Comment: @augustoccesar it then expected a `=> expression` but I recieved another exception: no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into Array.

Comment: It has to be something other than what you've presented. Is it kicking back with validation errors?

Comment: @TomL I don't have any validation on my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple problems with my code

1. Rather than `form_for :model` I should have had `form_for @model`
2. My `product_params` should have been:

   ```
   params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :description, :is_active, {:product_prices_attributes => [:id, :product_id, :start_date, :end_date, :price, :_destroy]})`
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem stems from eager loading product_prices in controller update action. I vaguely remember encountering a similar problem in the past but I can't find any documentation on it. Change:

```
 @model = Product.includes(:product_prices).find(params[:id])
```

To:

```
  @model = Product.find(params[:id])
```

See if that works.

Comment: Whoops! That was my fault. I updated my controller code. I accidentally posted the updated method rather than the create method!

Answer (score 0):

your product params should be in a private method..

```
private
def product_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:id, :name, :description, :is_active,   product_prices_attributes: [:id, :product_id, :start_date, :end_date, :price, :_destroy])
end
```

also product_prices and product_prices_attributes are not the same

Comment: Sorry, I should have included private in the original post, I already had I. However, after removing `attributes` from `product_prices`, I receive the following error: ProductPrice(#86342480) expected, got Array(#3601080). I tried the following syntax to: `product_prices: [{:id, :product_id, :start_date, :end_date, :price, :_destroy}]` with no such luck.

Comment: Also tried: `params.require(:model).permit(:id, :name, :description, :is_active, {:product_prices => [:id, :product_id, :start_date, :end_date, :price, :_destroy]})`

Comment: the correct syntax would be :product_prices => [:id, :product_id, ...] without the {} in Rails 4.2.4+

Comment: That didn't seem to resolve the issue. Still receiving the same error.